# How to save Data on the local Storage in React

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs

Im new in React and I wanted to build an App for my Android Smartphone.

I'm testing this now and it worked until I wanted to save some Data, because every time I close the App, the Data I want to keep is deleted.
I searched for a option to solve this problem and I tried it with asyncstorage, which I think is out of date, and with localStorage, which , when I install it as an apk on my phone, no longer works....

Are there other options or does it have to work with either one? Or am I completely on the wrong path and it works completely differently?

I've tried different things but somehow I'm doing something wrong.

Edit:
With LocalStorage.setItem() and .getItem() it worked at least in the web browser. So I don't think it's the code maybe?

App.js :

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, KeyboardAvoidingView, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Keyboard } from 'react-native';
import Task from './components/Task';

export default function App() {

  if (localStorage.getItem("storedtasks") == null) {
    var storedtasks = new Array;
  } else {
    var storedtasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("storedtasks"));
  }

  const [task, setTask] = useState();

  const handleAddTask = () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    storedtasks.push(task);
    localStorage.setItem('storedtasks', JSON.stringify(storedtasks));
    setTask("");
  }

  const completeTask = (index) => {
    storedtasks.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('storedtasks', JSON.stringify(storedtasks));
    window.location.reload();
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      
      {/*Today's Tasks */}
      <View style={styles.tasksWrapper}>
        <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Today's Tasks</Text>

        <View style={styles.items}>
          {/* This is where the tasks will go */}
          {
            storedtasks.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => completeTask(index)}>
                  <Task text={item} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )
            })
          }

        </View>

      </View>

      {/* Write a task */}
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
        style={styles.writeTaskWrapper}
      >
        <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={'Write a Task.'} value={task} onChangeText={text => setTask(text)}/>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleAddTask()}>
          <View style={styles.addWrapper}>
            <Text style={styles.addText}>+</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </KeyboardAvoidingView>


    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#E8EAED',
    //alignItems: 'center',
    //justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  tasksWrapper: {
    paddingTop: 80,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  items: {
    marginTop: 30,
  },
  writeTaskWrapper: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 60,
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  input: {
    paddingVertical: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    borderRadius: 60,
    borderColor: '#C0C0C0',
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: 250,
  },
  addWrapper: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    borderRadius: 60,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderColor: '#C0C0C0',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  addText: {},
});
```

Task.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Task = (probs) => {
    

    return (
        <View style={styles.item}>
            <View style={styles.itemLeft}>
                <View style={styles.square}></View>
                <Text style={styles.itemText}>{probs.text}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.circular}></View>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    item: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        padding: 15,
        borderRadius: 10,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        marginBottom: 20,
    },
    itemLeft: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
    },
    square: {
        width: 24,
        height: 24,
        backgroundColor: '#55BCF6',
        opacity: 0.4,
        borderRadius: 5,
        marginRight: 15,
    },
    itemText: {
        maxWidth: '80%',
    },
    circular: {
        width: 12,
        height: 12,
        borderColor: '#55BCF6',
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderRadius: 5,
    },
});

export default Task;
```

Comment: Are you using react native?

Comment: Can you share your code ? It will be better if you have a sandbox

Comment: Yes i added the code

Answer (score 0):

Since AsyncStorage is Deprecated! In React Native
use [react-native-mmkv](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv) Which is 30x faster than AsyncStorage!

> npm install react-native-mmkv

You can use this like

SET:

```
import { MMKV } from 'react-native-mmkv';

MMKV.set('user.name', 'Marc')
MMKV.set('user.age', 20)
MMKV.set('is-mmkv-fast-asf', true)
```

GET:

```
import { MMKV } from 'react-native-mmkv';

const username = MMKV.getString('user.name') // 'Marc'
const age = MMKV.getNumber('user.age') // 20
const isMmkvFastAsf = MMKV.getBoolean('is-mmkv-fast-asf') // true
```

DELETE:

```
import { MMKV } from 'react-native-mmkv';
MMKV.delete('user.name')
```

See More Documentation [here](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv)

Comment: Thank you. I will try it. 
How could I find something like this? How did you search?

Comment: Throught React Native official website. There are multiple suggestions of libraries to use in replacement of AsyncStorage.

Comment: I'm using expo. Is there a Problem with MMKV and Expo?
I tried MMKV but I get an error "MMKV.getString is not a function".

Comment: No Problem. Try It. it should support expo.

Comment: Is there a complete Userguide for the setup? I tested it with this website:
[https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv) and [https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv/blob/master/INSTALL.md](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv/blob/master/INSTALL.md) the With react-native-reanimated. it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [react-native-async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage)

With npm:

```
npm install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

With Yarn:

```
yarn add @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

With Expo CLI:

```
expo install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage)

Comment: But is async-storage not Deprecated?

Comment: Not this one @Zniets

Comment: I added this to save:<br/>
```AsyncStorage.setItem('storedtasks', JSON.stringify(storedtasks));```<br/>

and this to get the data:
```var storedtasks = JSON.parse(AsyncStorage.getItem("storedtasks"));```

But if I restart the App, the Data is not saved.